# Dashed line with equal length dashes in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [dashed] (0,0) -- (1.7,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I get the dashed line to have dashes of equal length? I don't actually mind if the dashed line doesn't start directly on the coordinates I specify, but I want to be able to specify a start and end coordinate and obtain a dashed line without trailing short bits.